# PHP Erro showing up "unexpected 'mail' "

Tags: php, html, forms, email

**Hey guys im so new to PHP and im still learing i made small website and made a conatct form and i need to get that infromation to my email I watched some you tube tutorials and did some coding and some erro is showng up.plz help me out.........**

*( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mail' (T_STRING) in C:\wampp\www\contact\contact.php on line 21*

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to='w.anjanadep@gmail.com';
$subject ="Message from Astaqua.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$message=$_POST['message'];


$message='name:'.$_POST['name'].'<br>'.
         'subject:'.$_POST['subject'].'<br>'.
         'Phone:'.$_POST['Phone'].'<br>'.
         'message:'.$_POST['message'];

$header ='From:{$email}\r\n'.
'Cc:astaquag@gmail.com\r\n'.
'Content-Type:text/html;'

mail=($to,$subject,$message, $header);
}
>?
```

Comment: Change `mail=(` to `mail(`

Comment: if mail is variable then use `$mail` but as @B001ᛦ said, I think mail is function then use `mail(...)`.

Comment: You forgot the semi-colon right before `mail=`(or put it in the wrong spot since it's inside of the quotes), which has been pointed out is  also incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your semi-colon is inside your header string, and you are assigning `mail` instead of calling the function. Change the last couple of lines to this

```php
$header ='From:{$email}\r\n'.
'Cc:astaquag@gmail.com\r\n'.
'Content-Type:text/html';

mail($to,$subject,$message, $header);
```

Normally when you have an error like

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mail'
```

it means you forgot a semi-colon on the line before.

Answer (score 0):

Current php think mail is a a constant. But mail would be a funktion then change your last line to:
`mail($to,$subject,$message, $header);`

Answer (score 0):

Mail is a function not a variable - remove the =

It should be:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message, $header);
```